# How to write the sql query to output the price formatted to include local currency symbol and formatted as 5 digits followed by two decimal places?

Tags: sql, oracle

Write the SQL to output the price of each appliance repair formatted to include the local currency symbol and formatted as 5 digits followed by two decimal places. Change the name of the column in the output to be REPAIR COST.

i tried using cast decimal, truncate, convert for the decimal part but it doesn't work

```
repairCost number(6,2) constraint chk_repair_cost check(repaircost between 60.50 and 160.30)

insert into appRepair(serialNo,  repairDate, repairDesc, repairCost, customer_id) values (
9001,       '04 Mar 2018',  'DVD  Stuck',   67.50, 1001);

SELECT concat('€', repairCost) as repairCost from appRepair;
```

expected output of price of each appliance repair formatted to include the local currency symbol and formatted as 5 digits followed by two decimal places, column name AS REPAIR COST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` with the [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28285/sqlqr07.htm#CHDIHDDB) `L` for local currency, `9` for an optional digit, `0` for a leading/trailing zero and `D` for a decimal character:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( repairCost, 'L99990D00' ) AS "REPAIR COST"
FROM   appRepair
```